# Kernel debugger does not crash system with .crash

Tags: windows, windbg, windows-kernel

I'm trying to create a fake system crash to create a dumpfile, and according to the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/crashing-and-rebooting-the-target-computer), I can enter the `.crash` command. I can successfully connect to the kernel with windbg, however when I execute the crash command it closes the kernel debugger window (and presumably the kernel debugger, <strike>some output is generated, but I can't read it as the window quickly closes</strike>)

I also tried `kd` with the command `kd -kl` and then running the crash command and now see the messages logged after running it:

```
lkd> .crash
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\atlmfc.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\concurrency.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\cpp_rest.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\stl.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\Windows.Data.Json.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\Windows.Devices.Geolocation.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\Windows.Devices.Sensors.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\Windows.Media.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\windows.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\winrt.natvis'
NatVis script unloaded from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\Visualizers\Kernel.natvis'
```

why does the command close the debugger and not crash the system? My version is listed as *Windows 10 17763 x64*

Comment: are you doing .crash with kd -kl  you cant crash your own local machine   you can crash only a debugee (either vm or another physical machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kd -kl is local kernel debugging

.crash is available only in live kernel debugging

your debuggee or target needs to be either a vm running the os or another physical machine 
connected to the debugger running on the host machine

issuing the .crash will do a manually initiated crash bugcheck and will write a kernel dump in the target  (probably name memory.dmp in windows\systemxxx folder )

see a gif note the bugcheck code on blueface

[image]